# Calculator Regular Expression with decimal number and normal number

Tags: regex, flutter, expression, calculator

I currently have a validation function with regex as below:

```
validateFormula(String value) {
    String pattern = (r'^\d+\.\d{1,2}$');
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Number cannot be empty";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Number not valid, always use decimal formaters. Ex: 1.0";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The code above runs to do calculations in a simple calculator application, but only for input numbers in the form of decimal with decimal. Examples `4.0 + 4.2`, etc. Like the picture below:

[image]

But, when I enter a number instead of a decimal number, it doesn't want to be counted because the regex that I created is only for decimal numbers.

[image]

How if I want to count as below:

```
1.6 + 1
1.66 + 1.66
1.667 - 1.111
1 * 1
1.56 / 1.56
```

With a maximum of 3 digits behind the decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use this regex:

```
^[+-]?\d+((\.\d{,3})|\d*)$
```

To allow positive and negative integers or decimal numbers having at most three digits after the decimal point.